# Trying to get the members of a specific class in an ontology

Tags: java, instance, jena, ontology

I am using Jena java API in order to read/search an ontology, and I am trying to find all the members of a specific class of the ontology.

So, I use the following code:

```
OntClass oc = model.getOntClass(NS + "ClassName");
for (ExtendedIterator<? extends OntResource> i = oc.listInstances(); i.hasNext();)
{
    OntResource or = i.next();
    System.out.println("Local name:" + or.getLocalName()); 
}
```

Where `model` is the `OntModel` object the ontology is read with.

The result I get from this code is a list of values in the form: className1, className5 etc.

When I open the ontology with Protege though, the members of the same class have normal names. Is `getInstances()` the right function for my purpose? And if so, where are the names I see with Protege stored in the ontology and how can I get their values?

Comment: @Alexis Pigeon
Ok, seriously, what is the problem on trying to be nice?
I know nobody is obligated to help me or something, that's why I want to say thank you to anyone that bothers....why did you have to correct that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop itself is fine. Your call to `.localName()` is pulling out the part of the URI that's (usually) the name part of a `prefix:name` qname pair. This is often a meaningful string of characters, as `myontology:Wheel` or `myontology:Truck`, but it isn't formally defined in the RDF standard and, strictly speaking, RDF treats whole URI's as single tokens without any internal structure.

When you're processing the ontology in code, the URI of the resource (or class, property, individual, etc) is what you need to refer to that resource. However, in presenting the resource to a human, via some sort of UI, you need something more readable. There are a number of conventions for this in RDF (unfortunately, that's conventions plural). Typically, you'll find one or more of the following properties attached to the resource:

- `rdfs:label` - typically used for compact readable names
- `rdfs:comment` - typically used for longer, more descriptive terms
- `skos:prefLabel` - 'preferred' label
- `skos:altLabel` - 'alternative' label

Most ontologies or datasets will use either `rdfs:comment` and `rdfs:label`, or the SKOS terms. Some will use both. Bear in mind that the labels may well have language-tagged variants as well:

```
<http://example.org/terms#Cat>
  a owl:Class ;
  rdfs:label "cat"@en ;
  rdfs:label "chat"@fr ;
  rdfs:comment "denotes the set of all cats"@en ;
  rdfs:comment "désigne l'ensemble de tous les chats"@fr .
```

So what Protege will be doing is looking to see which of these properties are being used in the ontology being edited, picking a preferred one, and then displaying that. You can do the same, for example:

```
OntClass oc = model.getOntClass(NS + "ClassName");
for (ExtendedIterator<? extends OntResource> i = oc.listInstances(); i.hasNext();)
{
  OntResource or = i.next();
  Property labelProp = null;

  if (or.hasProperty( RDFS.label )) {
    labelProp = RDFS.label;
  }
  else if (or.hasProperty( SKOS.prefLabel )) {
    labelProp = SKOS.prefLabel;
  }

  // note: does not deal with lang tags
  String label = (labelProp != null) ? or.getProperty( labelProp ).getString() : "unknown";

  System.out.println("Resource " + or.getURI() + " is labelled: " + label ); 
}
```

Comment: Thx for your detailed answer, it totally helped :)